# How to create label with multiple dynamic values with echart?

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, echarts

I want to add more content to the echarts(doughnut chart) legend like the following picture.

**From this**

[[image: s]

**To this**

[image]

Regards,
Eric

Comment: Hi Eric, what exactly do you mean "more content" ?

Comment: Hi lan,
Thanks for your support, the meaning of more content is like the following picture:
https://i.postimg.cc/J00rRQbF/capture.png 
I didn't find any attribute to achieve it at first, but now i achieve it through splicing html string, then get a variable. Like the following code:
https://i.postimg.cc/FHhXgZ6J/image.png

Thanks Again

Answer (score 3):

I'v added something like this on pie chart, in my case, I wanted to add the value after name, and all that I do was:

```
 legend: {
  show: props.legend ? true : false,
  orient: 'horizontal',
  x: 'left',
  y: 'bottom',
  formatter: props.legendValue ? function (name) {
    let itemValue = data.filter(item => item.name === name)
    return `${name}: ${itemValue[0].value}`
} : "{name}",
  data: props.legend
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its worked

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    initChart()
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => myChart.current.resize())

    axios.get('api/xxx/xxx').then(res => {
      myChart.current.setOption({
        legend: {
          formatter: function (name) {
            const _data = res.data.groups
            const _value = _data.filter(item => item.name === name)[0].value
            return `${name}  -  ${_value}`
          }
        },
        series: [{
          data: res.data.groups
        }]
      })
    })

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', () => myChart.current.resize())
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

if you mean `more space`, you can use option `series.center` , more [detail](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-pie.center)

> Center position of Pie chart, the first of which is the horizontal
>   position, and the second is the vertical position.
>
> Percentage is supported. When set in percentage, the item is relative
>   to the container width, and the second item to the height.

check this demo:

```js
let echartsObj = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#canvas'));
 
option = {
    color:['#429eda', '#8490ca', '#e97f74', '#f8d368', '#93cb76'],
    legend: {
        orient: 'vertical',
        x: 'right',
        y: 'center',
        data:['America','Canada','Japan','Mexico','India']
    },
    series: [
        {
 
            type:'pie',
            radius: ['50%', '70%'],
            startAngle: 170,
            center: ['30%', '50%'],
            label: {
                normal: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'center'
                },
                emphasis: {
                    show: true,
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: '30',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
            labelLine: {
                normal: {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            data:[
                {value:835, name:'America'},
                {value:310, name:'Canada'},
                {value:314, name:'Japan'},
                {value:135, name:'Mexico'},
                {value:948, name:'India'}
            ]
        }
    ]
};


    echartsObj.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
      <header>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```